# Partitions of unity from PMA Rudin

Tags: multivariable-calculus

[image]

It's partitions of unity theorem from PMA Rudin. Rudin asserts that exists function $\varphi\in C(\mathbb{R}^n)$ such that $\varphi(x)=1$ on $B(x)$ and $\varphi(x)=0$ outside $W(x)$. But it's not so obvious to me.

Can anyone explain to me in detail why such function exists?

**Edit:** Rudin's wrote property $(b)$ is clear, i.e. each $\psi_i$ has its support in some $V_{\alpha}$.

$\text{supp}(\psi_{i+1})=\text{cl}\{x: \psi_{i+1}(x)\neq 0\}=\text{cl}\{x: (1-\varphi_1)\dots(1-\varphi_i)\varphi_{i+1}\neq 0\}$.

Since $(1-\varphi_1)\dots(1-\varphi_i)\varphi_{i+1}\neq 0$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $\varphi_1\neq 1, \dots, \varphi_i\neq 1$ and $\varphi_{i+1}\neq 0.$

But $\varphi_1\neq 1$ on some $U_1\subset B(x_1)^c, \dots, \varphi_i\neq 1$ on some $U_i\subset B(x_i)^c$ and $\varphi_{i+1}\neq 0$ on some $U_{i+1}\subset \overline{W(x_i)}$.

Hence $$\text{supp}(\psi_{i+1})\subset \overline{W(x_i)}\cap B(x_1)^c \cap \dots \cap B(x_i)^c=\overline{W(x_i)} \cap (B(x_1)\cup \dots \cup B(x_i))^c=$$$$=\overline{W(x_i)}\setminus (B(x_1)\cup \dots \cup B(x_i))\subseteq \overline{W(x_i)} \subset V_{\alpha(x_i)}.$$
Hence $\text{supp}(\psi_{i+1})$ lies in some $V_{\alpha}$.

Is my proof right?

Comment: See [Urysohn's Lemma](http://homepage.math.uiowa.edu/~jsimon/COURSES/M132Fall07/UrysohnLemma_v5.pdf)

Comment: @Chilango, So Rudin uses lemma which is not trivial?

Comment: @Chilango, Strangely because it's very non-trivial fact and it never mind before in Rudin's book.

Comment: You don't need such a powerful tool. I will write up an example.

Comment: In $R^n$ you can actually define "bump" functions which have the required properties. I forgot if Rudin gives examples of such. Urysohn is very useful generally though and is well worth learning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $B(x)$ have radius $b$, $W(x)$ have radius $w$, we have $b < w$.

Define $v(t) = \begin{cases}
1, & 0 \le t < b \\
1-{t-b \over w-b}, & b \le t < w \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$

Let $\phi(y) = v(\|x-y\|)$. Since $v$ and $\|\cdot\|$ are continuous we see
that $\phi$ is continuous.

**Aside**:

Note that if $\phi_{i+1}(x) = 0$ then $\psi_{i+1}(x) = 0$ hence
$\operatorname{supp} \psi_{i+1} \subset \operatorname{supp} \phi_{i+1}\subset \overline{W(x_{i+1})} \subset V_{\alpha(x_{i+1})}$.

Comment: Nice example! +1. But is your $v$ is continuous at 1? because from the right side it's +1 but from the left it's 0.

Comment: @RFZ: I'm not sure what you mean. $v$ is continuous on the range of the norm, so the composition is continuous, If you don't like that, you can extend $v$ to the right and left with appropriate values so it is continuous.

Comment: Thank you! May I ask you one more question about above excerpt from Rudin's book?

Comment: @RFZ: Sure, I may not have time to answer it now, but ask away!

Comment: I wrote my answer above in my post. I would be very grateful for you if you'll check my answer.

Comment: @RFZ: I couldn't follow what you were doing above (wine+tired), I added a note to my answer with a simple argument.

Comment: I guess that you made a typo since $\text{supp}\phi_{i+1}\subset \overline{W(x_{i+1})}$ but you wrote $\overline{B(x_{i+1})}$ because possibly there are points $z\in W(x_{i+1})\setminus \overline{B(x_{i+1})}$ at which $f(z)\neq 0$. Am I right?

Comment: @RFZ: You are correct, thanks for catching that. Some day I will write an answer without typos. :-).

Answer (score 2):

The function $$\varphi(x) := \begin{cases} e^{-1/(1-x^2)} : & |x| < 1; \\ 0: & |x| \ge 1; \end{cases}$$ is $C^{\infty}$, positive and zero outside of $[-1,1].$

Its integral $\psi(x) = \int_0^x \varphi(t) \, \mathrm{d}t$ is constant zero left of $-1$ and a positive constant right of $1$.

By adding rescaling and shifting $\psi(x)$ and $\psi(-x)$ to the left or right, you can find a $C^{\infty}$ function $f$ that is constant $1$ on $[-\varepsilon/2,\varepsilon/2]$ and constant $0$ outside of $(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon),$ for any $\varepsilon > 0.$ In several variables, you can take the product $u(x_1)...u(x_n)$ for the same effect.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $U,V$ are open in $X$ a metric space and $\overline U\subseteq V$. Then you can define $f(x) = d(x,V^c) /( d(x,V^c)+d(x,U))$ and note first, that $f$ is continuous, since $d(x,V^c)+d(x,U)>0$ always: if it is zero then $x\in \overline U$ and $x\notin V$, which is impossible. Second, $f(x)=1$ if $x\in U$, and if $x\notin V$ then $f(x)=0$. In fact $f$ is nonzero if and only if $x\in V$, and it is one precisely if $x\in \overline U$. This has the disadvantage of being potentially nonsmooth, but you can always smooth it out by taking a convolution with an appropriate function.

Comment: Nice example! Thank you very much!